# Windows 10 Ubuntu WSL freezes randomly

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu Windows-Subsystem-for-Linux through Microsoft Store on my Windows 10 laptop, but it freezes randomly, for example when I run a command such as `ls -l`, `gcc -o` or even when the bash starts. What happens is that the whole bash just freezes, it doesn't run any command I type and many processes named `bash`, `node` and `init` appear in the Windows task manager which use close to 100% of the CPU. These processes can not be terminated through the Task Manager and they only close when I reboot the computer.

[image: Task Manager]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Ubuntu WSL from the Microsoft Store, installing different Ubuntu WSL versions, updating Windows 10 and creating a new Windows User. This issue appeared suddenly, as some days ago everything was working fine.